# rails+jquery confirmation message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

i am updating record through jquery, and once data is updated how can one display success/failure message.

i have used following code to update data through jquery,

```
var data = {user_id:userId, user_type:$("#userType").val()};
 var url = "<%= url_for(updateUser_path)%>";

$.get(url, data)
```

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respond with json once you update data, and then process normally with jquery, for example:

```
$.get(url, data, function(resp_data){
    if (resp_data.status == 'ok') {
       alert(resp_data.ok_msg)
    } else {
       ...
    }
    ...
}, 'json')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer about json, if you want to integrate more tightly with rails you should check out unobtrusive javascript, and use it in conjunction with a :remote => true form.